# Problema com números em PHP

Tags: php, float

Eu tenho o seguinte exercicio em PHP:

O custo de um carro novo ao consumidor é a soma do custo de fábrica com
a porcentagem do distribuidor e dos impostos (aplicados ao custo de
fábrica). Supondo que o percentual do distribuidor seja de 28% e os
impostos de 45%, escrever um algoritmo para ler o custo de fábrica de um
carro, calcular e escrever o custo final ao consumidor.

Quando o valor do carro é um número sem casas decimais ele funciona corretamente.
Porem quando eu informo um valor como: 58.000,20.
Ele dá o seguinte erro:

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\exercicio06\pageImpostos.php on line 3

Aqui está o código: (são dois arquivos)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Valor do carro - Index</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script>
        function imposto() {
            if(document.formCarro.valor.value === ""){
                alert('INFORME ALGUM VALOR!');
                document.formCarro.valor.value();
            }else{
                document.formCarro.action='./pageImpostos.php';
                document.formCarro.submit();
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="formCarro" method="post" action="">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">CARRO</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="page-01">
                    <label for="valor">Valor do carro:</label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="valor" id="valor" size="22" maxlength="10" placeholder="EX: 00000,00">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="Calcular" name="btnCarro" id="btnCarro" onclick="imposto();">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
    $valor = $_REQUEST["valor"];
    $valor = $valor + ($valor * 0.28) + ($valor * 0.45);
?>



<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Valor do carro</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script>
        function volta() {
            document.formCarro.action='./index.php';
            document.formCarro.submit();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="formCarro" method="post" action="">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">CARRO</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="page-01">
                Valor final: <br>
                <?php echo number_format($valor, '2', ',', '.') ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Home" name="btnVolta" id="btnVolta" onclick="volta();">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente dar entrada com o valor 58000.20 ao invés de 58.000,20.
Creio que seja necessário validar a entrada desse dado porque no PHP os pontos flutuantes são nesse formato: 1.0 ou 5.44 e não 4,2 ou 5,6. Além disso não se pode ter o ponto separando os grupos de centena, milhar, etc.
Dê uma olhada em https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.float.php